# When passing an array to Twig, words with special characters are disappearing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, twig, non-ascii-characters

I can query data from the database use mysqli, output to Twig and create a table, and words with characters with accents(À, Í, etc) are not displayed.

The array can be displayed through a var_dump perfectly. So somewhere in Twig is it going awry.

**I have:**

- A database with data in Spanish
- PHP
- Silex/Twig
- A table schema in utf8, with text being displayed correctly.

**I have tried:**

- `mb_convert_encoding` before sending it to Twig
- `convert_encoding('iso-8859', 'UTF-8')` in Twig

I am at a loss as to what to do next, nor why it is not working. **If anyone knows why the entire word disappears, that would be great.**

**Template Example:**

```
{% if results %}
<div class="table-container" id="table-container">
    <table class="results-table" id="results-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ "First Name"|trans }}</th>
            <th>{{ "Second Name"|trans }}</T></th>
            <th>{{ "First Surname"|trans }}</th>
            <th>{{ "Second Surname"|trans }}</th>
            <th>{{ "Number"|trans }}</th>
            <th>{{ "Type"|trans }}</th>
            <th>{{ "District"|trans }}</th>
            <th>{{ "State"|trans }}</th>
            <th>{{ "City"|trans }}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="results">
        {% for r in results %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ r.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.middle_inital }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.surname }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.second_surname}}</td>
            <td>{{ r.number }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.district }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ r.city|capitalize }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

*Array is passed from a mysqli query to a variable. Text book example.*

Comment: Can you please show your template code, the code where you pass data to twig and example array?

Comment: Do you have the meta tag in your template (`<meta charset="UTF-8" />`)?

Comment: Did you make sure your browser is displaying the page as utf8?

Comment: @charmeleon Yes. `<meta charset="UTF-8"` is the first thing in the head.

Comment: @Maerlyn the browser is set to Unicode, but for whatever reason it is sending `windows-1252`. I haven't set it to send as such, and `utf-8` is coming from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:** `AddCharset UTF-8 .html .php`

**Recap:**

- MySQL/Silex/Twig application has data that is output to table
- Table data is correct
- **Words with special characters are not being rendered**
- Browser and Database is set the UTF-8

So, after some poking around, I saw to check the `HTTP header` being sent. It was set to `windows-1252`. This was forcing the browser to switch away from Unicode whenever the table was loaded.

I found a directive to place into `.htaccess` which would force `UTF-8` encoding. `AddCharset UTF-8 .html .php` forces `UTF-8` on all HTML and PHP pages.